# Beta badge not shown in count?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When looking to the badges page I see that I would have the beta badge (green checkmark). However, when looking to my badgecount, I don't have any silver badges.

Why is this? I see others are having the same problem. [This page](https://security.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta) says it all.

Comment: H-uh, same here, dint notice that. I assumed Beta was bronze... I WANT MY SILVER!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the manual award code -- we didn't see it before, because I just let the scheduler pick up the beta badge award in the past, but Geoff was awarding them manually.

Should be fixed in a few hours.

Comment: It is fixed now for me.

Comment: Me too. Yay! you guys rock!

Comment: I dunno - you guys and your silvers :-)